# postgresql: SUM with OR operator with an aggregation query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have successfully done following query:

```
SELECT rs.personid, rs.rec_count,
       sum(case when r.rectype = 'degreeOne' then 1 else 0 end)
```

but now I want to change this to following

```
SELECT rs.personid, rs.rec_count,
       sum(case when r.rectype = 'test1' then 1 else 0 end) OR sum(case when r.rectype = 'random' and r.badgeid = 'bronze' then 1 else 0 end) as degree_one, ...
```

basically I want to do sum with an `"OR"` operator, I tried as I have shown but it gives me an error.

Comment: I'm not a postgre expert, but I think you'd need a when/case.  The result of a boolean operation in SQL usually doesn't return a true/false that you can display in a SELECT clause(I know its annoying).  You'd need to do something like `CASE WHEN sum(...) OR sum(...) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sum (
    case
        when
            r.rectype = 'test1'
            or
            r.rectype = 'random' and r.badgeid = 'bronze'
            then 1
        else 0
    end
) as degree_one
```